# No puedo solucionar este error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Tags: python, python-3.7, opencv, img, ocr

que tal? estoy intentando hacer con Python 3 un programa para reconocer patentes de auto. Soy nuevo e inexperto y hace 3 dias no tengo idea de como solucionar este error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Cliente2\Desktop\OpenMastertest\EncontrarPlacaHD.py", line 122, in 
    findPlace(contornos, area)
  File "c:\Users\Cliente2\Desktop\OpenMastertest\EncontrarPlacaHD.py", line 32, in findPlace
    cv2.imwrite("C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/{}.jpg".format(time.time()), roi)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.8) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:740: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

La idea es que el programa identifique la patente, saque captura y a esa misma captura modifique la foto y que siga funcionando. Con este error el programa ni bien toma captura de la patente se cierra...
Bueno espero que puedan ayudarme, se los agradeceria mucho. Gracias!

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tkinter
import pytesseract
import cv2
import time
def findPlace(contornos, imagem):#

 for c in contornos:
     # Perimetro del contorno, verificar si el contorno esta cerrado
     perimetro = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
     #if perimetro > 200 and perimetro < 600:
     if perimetro > 200 and perimetro < 600:
        #aproxima los contornos a la forma correspondiente
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03 * perimetro, True)
        #comprobar si es un cuadrado o un rectángulo de acuerdo con el número de vértices

        if len(approx) == 4:
          #Contorna la placa a través de los contornos encontrados
          #cv2.drawContours(imagem, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
          (x, y, lar, alt) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
          cv2.rectangle(imagem, (x, y), (x + lar, y + alt), (0, 255, 0), 2)
          #segmenta la placa de imagen
          roi = imagem[(y+15):y+alt, x:x+lar]
          #guarda la imagen segmentada en "C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/"
          #cv2.imwrite("C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/roi.jpg", roi)
          cv2.imwrite("C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/{}.jpg".format(time.time()), roi)

 return imagem



def OCR(path_img):

 #Lea la entrada de la imagen y guárdela en la entrada variable
 entrada = cv2.imread(path_img + ".jpg")
 # cv2.imshow("ENTRADA", img)

 # Aumenta la resolucion de la imagen de la placa en 4x
 img = cv2.resize(entrada, None, fx=4, fy=4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

 # Convierte a escala de grises
 img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 # cv2.imshow("Escala Cinza", img)

 # Binariza la imagen (blanco y negro)
 ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 cv2.imshow("Limiar", img)

 # Desenfoca la imagen
 img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
 # cv2.imshow("Desfoque", img)

 # Guarde el resultado en la ruta de dirección + / ocr.jpg
 cv2.imwrite(path_img + "-ocr.jpg", img)

 # Abre la imagen grabada para el reconocimiento de OCR
 # y guarda el resultado en la salida variable
 imagem = Image.open(path_img + "-ocr.jpg")
 salida = pytesseract.image_to_string(imagem, lang='eng')

 # Realiza un filtro sobre los caracteres obtenidos. 
 # eliminando posibles ruidos reconocidos
 if len(salida) > 0:
     print(salida)
     texto = removerChars(salida)
 else:
     texto = "OCR fallo"

 janela = tkinter.Tk()
 tkinter.Label(janela, text=texto, font=("Helvetica", 50)).pack()
 janela.mainloop()

def removerChars(text):
 str = "!@#%¨&*()_+:;><^^}{`?|~¬\/=,.'ºª»‘"
 for x in str:
     text = text.replace(x, '')
 return text

#Captura de Video
#video = cv2.VideoCapture('')
video = cv2.VideoCapture('resource\\Prueba.mp4')

while(video.isOpened()):

 ret, frame = video.read()

 if(ret == False):
     break

 #area de localizacion
 area = frame[500: , 300:800]

 # escala de grises
 img_result = cv2.cvtColor(area, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 # umbral
 ret, img_result = cv2.threshold(img_result, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

 # desenfoque
 img_result = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_result, (5, 5), 0)

 # lista de contornos
 #img, contornos, hier = cv2.findContours(img_result, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
 #contornos, jerarquía = cv2.findContours (thresh, cv2. RETR_TREE , cv2. CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )
 img, contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_result, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

 # limite horizontal
 cv2.line(frame, (0, 500), (1280, 500), (0, 0, 255), 1)
 # limite vertical 1
 cv2.line(frame, (300, 0), (300, 720), (0, 0, 255), 1)
 # limite vertical 2
 cv2.line(frame, (800, 0), (800, 720), (0, 0, 255), 1)

 cv2.imshow('FRAME', frame)

 findPlace(contornos, area)

 cv2.imshow('RES', area)

 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
     break

video.release()
OCR("C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/roi")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hola Axel, según el error roi es un array vacío...

Comment: ¿Tal vez [eso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484177/how-to-remove-this-error-215assertion-failed-img-empty-in-function-cv) da alguna pista?  Hacer un `print((y+15):y+alt, x:x+lar)` antes de guardar la imagen podría aclarar si se trata de una imagen vacía.

Comment: Hola! disculpen la demora, me encargaron hacer otra cosa y recien retome el proyecto. Si,  creo que parece ser que es un array vacío. Al ver las variables locales en "cv2.imwrite("C:/Tesseract-OCR/salidas/roi.jpg", roi)" aparece esto en roi max: "array is empty" / min: "array is empty". ¿Saben como solucionarlo? Muchas gracias por sus respuestas!!